# What causes checksum mismatch error while printing from OctoPrint?

Tags: octoprint, skr-mini-e3, serial-connection

Recently, I've installed a new BIGTREETECH SKR mini E3 V3.0 board on Creality Ender-5. Previously, I was using SKR mini E3 V1.2 board, but it broke down and I had to replace it. I connected new one exactly like the previous board and calibrated the printer. Everything seemed to be working properly.

Now, I'm getting unexpected `M122` errors while printing from OctoPrint:

[image: M122 error on printer's display]

This is OctoPrint's console output:

```
Recv: ok
Recv: Error:checksum mismatch, Last Line: 30869
Recv: Resend: 30870
Should resend line 30870 but no sufficient history is available, can't resend
Changing monitoring state from "Printing" to "Error"
Send: G1 X109.711 Y118.883 E.02691
Send: M112
Send: N31035 M112*37
Send: N31036 M104 T0 S0*38
Send: N31037 M140 S0*99
Changing monitoring state from "Error" to "Offline after error"
Connection closed, closing down monitor
Closing down send loop
```

This checksum mismatch error appears randomly at different stages of printing, but always around 30000 line.

---

**What is my setup?**

- Creality Ender-5
- Raspberry Pi 3A+
- OctoPrint 1.8.6
- OctoPi 0.18.0
- SKR mini E3 V3.0 board
- [My custom firmware](https://github.com/kosteklvp/Marlin-SKR-mini-E3-v3/tree/209c69f887105b52191fd1c229e103a0a27b5862/Marlin)

I customized the firmware from BIGTREETECH official repository for this board. This problem also occurs, when I upload official firmware for this board. OctoPrint is connected to the board via GPIO pins - that's how it was connected before and I have no way to connect it via USB cable.

---

**What have I done to resolve this issue?**

- Tried printing from SD card. This error doesn't occur, when printing from SD card.
- Replaced cables connecting the board with Raspberry Pi.
- Isolated all the electronics away from the printer's case.
- Changed SD card used by OctoPrint to a new, empty one.
- Updated OctoPrint to recent, stable version.
- Uninstalled all unnecessary OctoPrint plugins.
- Tried flashing official firmware.

I suppose that the problem is in the connection between the printer and OctoPrint. What can cause this error to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Marlin docs](https://marlinfw.org/docs/configuration/configuration.html#baud-rate), these checksum mismatch errors were due to the baud rate being set incorrectly.

> The serial communication speed of the printer should be as fast as it can manage without generating errors. In most cases 115200 gives a good balance between speed and stability. Start with 250000 and only go lower if “line number” and “checksum” errors start to appear.

Lowering baud rate solved the problem.